# What is the best way to build code which is stored in public repo and need token key with CI?

Tags: android, github, travis-ci, android-build

I have an Android project that need token key which I store in a public repo. I do not commit my key to the repo. I integrate my repo with Travis CI for automated build. But, the building process will be failed because no token key is found. How should I provide the key to the CI without committing it to the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travis allows you to store encrypted environment variables for precisely this scenario. See [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypting-environment-variables):

> ## Encrypting environment variables
>
> Encrypt environment variables with the public key attached to your repository using the `travis` gem:
>
> 1. If you do not have the `travis` gem installed, run `gem install travis`.
> 2. In your repository directory, run:
>
>    ```
>     travis encrypt MY_SECRET_ENV=super_secret --add env.matrix
>    ```
> 3. Commit the changes to your `.travis.yml`.
>
> > *Encryption and decryption keys are tied to the repository. If you fork a project and add it to Travis CI, it will not access to the encrypted variables.*
>
> The encryption scheme is explained in more detail in [Encryption keys](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys).